# Detect records older than 'X' hours SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that includes the creation date and creation time of records in two separate columns.

```
SELECT
T0.[ID] AS ' ID',
T0.[customer] AS 'Customer Name',
T0.[status] AS 'Status',
T0.[createDate] AS 'Creation Date',
T0.[createTime] AS 'Creation Time' 

FROM

[ret].[MRCL] T0

WHERE

T0.[status] Like N'%-3%'
```

The creation dates are stored as DATE such as

```
10.05.17
09.03.17
```

The time for some reason (Out of my control) are stored as a number from (-32,768 to: 32,767) such as

```
15:20
10:56
09:25
```

**I am looking for a way to filter out records older than '2' hours.**

Comment: What does "15:20" have to do with a number from "32,768 to: 32,767" [sic]?

Comment: how are you converting those numbers to a time format?

Comment: bad database design. creation date and time belongs together and should be stored in one column

Comment: Upvoting all the above, what are the types of the date and time columns?  It could get nasty trying to work with these separately, e.g. the few hours around the start of a new day.

Comment: The initial table was not designed by myself. I'm working on a report based off of the table.

The only information i can supply is that the date is a DATE and time is just stored as a number. It's not possible for me to go and change these.

Comment: Be that as it may, if you don't know what the numbers represent, you can't do anything.  You have to find out.

Comment: As for the '15:20' Gordon. That was an error which i've corrected in the original post.

The results that are shown on screen show the times in the format i've mentioned above and I can see that the datatype as a number. This may be incorrect but there's no way for me to actually check.

Comment: Can you explain how you convert the number 32,767 into a time? Without that information you're not going to be able to do this.

Comment: You say that the numbers are displayed in the correct format, is this in a report? If so, can you get the definition of that report to see how it's converting those numbers to a time format?

Comment: I've managed to find the table I'm using and I'm able to see the exact datatypes.

The creationdate is actually a DATETIME datatype. I was unaware of this as the program in which the records are displayed just mention it as being DATE.

Although it's a DATETIME datatype. Only the date is shown. As for how the createtime number (smallint) is converted to a time, that is still something I'm trying to figure out.

As you can probably tell, i'm not highly experienced in SQL. I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: After some digging around on google I think the time is converted directly from a number to time.

Such as.

0925 = 09:25,
1005 = 10:05,
1353 = 13:53,
2335 = 23:35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is painful, but to things SARGable to take advantage of any available indexes, we can create parameters to fulfill the criteria instead of converting the table columns into something that actually makes sense.

Using `convert()` styles and `replace()` to generate the `smallint` time format being used in the table:

```
declare @hoursbefore int = 16;
declare @beforeDate date = convert(date,dateadd(hour,-@hoursbefore,getdate()));
declare @beforeTimeSmallint smallint = convert(smallint,replace(convert(char(5),dateadd(hour,-@hoursbefore,getdate()),108),':',''));
```

And use like so:

```
select *
from t
where t.[status] like N'%-3%'
  and ( CreateDate < @beforeDate 
    or (CreateDate = @beforeDate and CreateTime < @beforeTimeSmallint)
    )
```

Breakdown of the conversion:

```
declare @beforeTimeSmallint smallint =
  convert(smallint
    ,replace(
      convert(char(5)
        ,dateadd(hour,-@hoursbefore,getdate()) /* reduce current date by amount of hours */
        ,108 /* time as hh:mi:ss */  )
      ,':','') /* replacing the semicolon */
      );
```